# Can eclipse do auto-complete using external libraries like cocos2d?

Tags: c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, cocos2d-android

I'm using Eclipse in linux. I have created a project using Cocos2D. It's a Java project, but im opening cpp and headers files to write native code.

Each time, i compile the native code with ./build_native.sh

I will like to know if eclipse could be configure to autocomplete functions in native code.

Example:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->
```

Must show the options like getWinSize().

Some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer to the specifics of your question but in general I had this problem in C/C++ with iostream and STL libs. Even though everything would compile fine it wasn't supporting auto-complete. I ended up digging down into the supplied libraries to the root that held each .h file collection and added those to the directories path. Then I rebuilt the index and then auto-complete started working. So if cocos2d stores .h files in more than one location add each folder.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)? That give Eclipse C/C++ capabilities similar to what it already has for Java.

Comment: Yes, i have CDT main features installed, and CDT Optional features. I can create c++ projects and compile it